# Memory address received from Apple's crash report not readable

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, crash-reports

I've received crash report on my submitted iOS app from apple, which is:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   APPNAME                 0x00071fc8 0x6d000 + 20424
1   APPNAME                 0x000733ce 0x6d000 + 25550
2   APPNAME                 0x00072cc0 0x6d000 + 23744
3   Foundation                      0x354cd2ee 0x354bb000 + 74478
.....
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3707bebc 0x37073000 + 36540
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3707bdc4 0x37073000 + 36292
GraphicsServices                0x36835418 0x36831000 + 17432
17  GraphicsServices                0x368354c4 0x36831000 + 17604
18  UIKit                           0x35f25d62 0x35ef7000 + 191842
19  UIKit                           0x35f23800 0x35ef7000 + 182272
20  APPNAME                 0x0006ed46 0x6d000 + 7494
21  APPNAME                 0x0006ed10 0x6d000 + 7440
```

I've also been looking at atos command and dwarfdump. I have both .dsym and the .app that was submitted to apple. However, I couldn't find a thing using the memory address given by apple (ex. 0x0006ed46, 0x00071fc8, etc. ). I tried randomizing address and found that my application address is actually between 0x0002xxx to 0x0007xxx

What happened? How can I know which part of my application causes the bug?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You need to symbolicate your crash report using the dsym file.  You can see the answer here:

[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)